# How to open a form from a Dialog (modal form) and make it accesible even if didn't close the dialog

Tags: winforms, modal-dialog, vb.net-2010

I have a form (form1) that I open as modal. In that form there is a button where, when the user presses it, it opens a new form (form2).

I have the problem that form1 is modal and form2 is in the background, and I cannot do anything until I close form1. How can I do stuff in form2 without closing form1?

I need form1 to be modal, I cannot change that. I tried to set the parent of form2 when calling it:

```
form2.Parent = form1
form2.Show()
```

But it gave me an error:

> "Form cannot be added to the Controls collection that has a valid MDI
>   parent. Parameter name: value"

So I tried this:

```
form1.IsMdiContainer = true
```

But this just puts form2 inside form1. I also tried hiding form1 and then showing it again when form2 is closed, but it fails.

Platform: [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) using VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having was that it was setting the parent of form2 as the mainform, so I deleted that part and now form2 opens on top of form1.

Another solution that also works is to open form2 as modal. Of course it will act different, but that depends on what you want.